# ember-cli-chart addon is not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-addon

I've downloaded ember-cli-chart addon from emberaddons.com

I followed the screencast but as soon as I refresh the page it gives me error "ember-chart is not a helper". I looked up the internet but unfortunately found nothing.

It seems to me that ember is trying to find a component but failed so it assumes I'm calling a helper, which obviously I'm not.

I generated a component with the name "ember-chart" but it shows nothing

```
{{ember-chart type="bar" data=departmentsStatistics}}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Habe you restarted ember-cli after installing the addon?

Comment: how did you download it? Is it in your package.json?